# Unter vs unterhalb?

Tags: word-choice

> Es war unter seiner Würde.

Why not:

> Es war unterhalb seiner Würde?

That seems to work with Duden's definition:

> unter etwas, tiefer als etwas gelegen

Comment: Given that it uses the genitive, it might help to think of *unterhalb* as "underneath" rather than "below". But as an English speaker I have no idea why the English expression isn't "underneath one's dignity" rather than "below one's dignity".

Comment: I am familiar with both variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition *»unterhalb«* is used only as a local preposition, i.e. describing the location of an item.
It is not used as modal preposition.

- local *"below", "underneath"*

  > Sie malte den Punkt **unterhalb** des Fensters an die Wand.
  > Die Nase befindet sich **unterhalb** der Stirn.
- <del>modal</del>

  > <del>Seine Leistung war **unterhalb** aller Sau.</del>

The preposition *»unter«* can be used as local preposition in two meanings (*below* and *among*) but also as a modal preposition.

- local *"below"*

  > Sie malte den Punkt **unter** dem Fenster an die Wand.
  > Die Nase befindet sich **unter** der Stirn.
- among *"among"*

  > Der Prinz mischte sich unerkannt **unter** das Volk.
  > Wenn man **unter** den Top 10 ist, bringt das nicht nur Vorteile mit sich.
- modal

  > Das mache ich nicht, das ist **unter** meiner Würde.
  > Ihm darf nichts geschehen, er befindet sich **unter** meiner Obhut.

Comment: I don't completely agree. _Unterhalb aller Sau_ ist strictly an idiom, so _unterhalb_ does not work -- but _unterhalb seiner Würde_ is still a transparent metaphorical construction. Yes, it is much less common than _unter_, but I find it a completely acceptable locative metaphor (UP = GOOD etc.).

Comment: @phipsgabler: Google-Suche (mit Anführungszeichen): "unter seiner Würde": Ungefähr 113 000 Ergebnisse. Aber "unterhalb seiner Würde": Ungefähr 560 Ergebnisse. Das ist ein Verhältnis von ca. 200 zu 1. Das ist ein schlechteres Verhältnis als "größer als" vs. "größer wie" (80 : 1)  oder "asozial" / "assozial" (16 : 1). In beiden Beispielen spricht man bei der selteneren Version schon ganz klar von einem Fehler und nicht mehr von "less common". Daher betrachte ich auch die Variante *»unterhalb seiner Würde«* schlichtweg als fehlerhaft.